# How can I implement input movement?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am new to UE and trying to make very simple game to learn the engine.

This is how the game looks

[image: This is how the game looks.]

I want the player to be able to move the cube(PlayerPawn) left and right only.

This is my script to move the pawn.

[image: This is my script to move the pawn]

But when I go left or right it also rotates. How can I fix this? How can I implement input movement while the pawn simulates physics?

Answer (score 0):

You're applying floating pawn movement on a non floating object? That just doesn't seem right does it?

If you want to use custom movement just setup a collision component (BoxComponent in your case maybe?) And apply forced with SetForce/AddImpulse or SetLinearVelocity.

Also might be worth your time looking into the Character blueprint clasd that comes with lot's of premade movement capabilities

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/js65E6y) Now I use the set velocity but this introduced a new problem. The cube is rotating when I move it. I know I can lock rotation but I need the cube to rotate when it hits something as it normally would.

Comment: It is rotating because it is simulating the physics. You're asking how to turn off the physics while keeping it turned on?

Comment: I think you should have a look at how to implement your own movement similar to the charactermovement component

Comment: If you rely on physics simulation purely you'll hit these problems 100% of the time

Comment: I need the pawn to simulate physics but I also need to be able to move it smoothly(without rotating). So, how can I do it?

Comment: You have to implement custom movement / customized physics simulation that looks just like the simulation of physics. You can rely on the physics simulation for collision detection